# Textbox in Gridview

Tags: .net, vb.net

How can I add text boxes within Gridview like this

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your gridview markup specify each column as a Template field:

```
<Columns>

                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email Address to Exclude">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblEmailAddress" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EmailAddress") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmailAddress" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EmailAddress") %>' class="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField></Columns>
```

ItemTemplate is how the cell appears when not editing, in this case displays a label.
EditItemTemplate is how the cell appears when editing, Displays a text box.

Comment: How to I populate data in it?